# Pull a function out of the integral?

Tags: calculus, probability

Given the equation:

\begin{gather*}
f(t) = \int_{\Omega }k(x)g(t, x)\,dx \\
\\
0 \leq t \leq  ∞ \\
a \leq x \leq b & a,b \in \mathbb{R}
\end{gather*}

If $k(x)$ is an unknown function but $f(t)$ and $g(t,x)$ are known - Can one bring $k(x)$ out of the integral to potentially solve for it?

Thank you!

Comment: What are the domains/spaces for each of the functions?

Answer (score 0):

There are cases, e.g. for a point charge in electrodynamics, where one can find an operator $L$ for which $g$ is a Green's function, then
$$
L f(t) 
= \int\limits_\Omega k(x) \, L \, g(x,t) \, dx
= \int\limits_\Omega k(x) \, \delta(x-t) \, dx
= k(t)
$$

Comment: That is interesting because the initial condition at $ g(0,x)= \delta(x-x0) $